# How do I create a "public" user profile page in ASP.NET (3.5)

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, user-controls

I implemented the ASP.NET user controls.

Each user can log in and update their personal data, for example on the private page `myData.html`

Now, I would like a part of their profile to be displayed on a public read-only page, for example -  `userGreg45public.html`

How do I implement or modify the user control, to allow each user to have their own **unique** public page?

(Note - There are a "set" of files that are named all the same for each user becuase they can only be accessed when a specific person logs in. For example, myData.html has the same name but displays different data based on who logs in. The "public page" will have to have a unique file name for each member)

Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the issue is you want each user to have their own url... Is this the case?

You can use URL Rewriting.  One of the more simple approaches is to use the [HttpContext.RewritePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.rewritepath.aspx) in the `Application_BeginRequest` method of your `Global.asax` file.

**EDIT:** Added Sample Code

I am making some assumptions here... The assumptions I am making are that a) users have a first name, b) users have a last name and c) users have some unique identifier, in my case I am using a "userId".

To start, you will have to decide on a format for the public urls.  Something like this could work:

```
http://www.yoursite.com/public/firstname-lastname-1234.aspx
```

Where 1234 is the userId.

Next, you will want a function to build these URLs.  Something like this perhaps:

```
String ToPublicUrl(String firstName, String lastName, int userId)
{
    return String.Format("http://www.yoursite.com/public/{0}-{1}-{2}.aspx",
        Regex.Replace(firstName, "[^a-zA-Z]", ""),
        Regex.Replace(lastName, "[^a-zA-Z]", ""),
        userId);
}
```

Notice how I am stripping out any non-letter characters.

Now, in the Global.asax file, add the following code:

```
static Regex ProfileRegex = new Regex(@"/public/(?<firstname>[a-zA-Z]+)-(?<lastname>[a-zA-Z]+)-(?<userid>[0-9]+)\.aspx$",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);

void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Match match = ProfileRegex.Match(Context.Request.FilePath);
    if( (match != null) && match.Success )
    {
        Context.RewritePath((String.Format("~/public/userProfile.aspx?userId={0}",
            match.Groups["userid"]));
    }
}
```

There is a lot of stuff going on here.  To start, by simply defining this function, ASP.Net will subscribe it to the [HttpApplication.BeginRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.beginrequest.aspx) event.

Next is the Regex which does the heavy lifting.  It basically matches any requests to your a user profile page, and internally tells ASP.Net to route the request to another page.  The new requests will look something like this:

```
http://www.yoursite.com/public/userProfile.aspx?userId=1234
```

It is up to you to implement the `/public/userProfile.aspx` page.  There are numerous ways to make things readonly.  It might be as straight forward as replacing [TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.aspx) controls with [Label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.aspx) controls?

If you have multiple pages you want to make public, you could implement multiple rewrite rules.  (Although at some point you are better off using a component like [this](http://urlrewriter.net/) or [this](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite)).

As an FYI, I referenced samples on [this page](http://dotnetperls.com/rewrite-aspnet) for the rewrite stuff.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank You very much. That gives me a much better idea of what is going on and what I need to do to create that url. It seems like the read-only should not be a big issue. I will take a stab at it this weekend, thanks again.

Comment: Dana, when and how does ToPublicUrl() get used? Thank You.

Comment: Also, I have the file "public\userProfile.aspx" but do I have to also create "userProfile.aspx?userId=1234" that it is going to point to? or does this code know to go to the userProfile.aspx page of that userID?

Comment: Hey Greg - ToPublicUrl() is a utility function that you can use whenever you need to generate the public url.  When a person is viewing their personal profile, you could show them a link to their "public" profile?  Or maybe have a listing of public profiles somewhere in your site?  As far as the userProfile.aspx page,  you only need one.  The code on that page should check Request.QueryString["userId"] and dynamically display the profile of the requested user.  Are you using a database to store user profile data?

Answer (score 2):

You can by default assign a role like "guest" to the user who has visited the site.

Answer (score 1):

I just implemented something like this on a site. I created two pages. One that was private and required the user to be logged in. This page allowed the user to edit their profile.

And the other page was a public page. It didn't allow edits, and it was in a location viewable by anyone.