# Are there security issues using ASP.NETs "UserProfileID" in a URL?

Tags: asp.net, security, url, user-controls

I have the user controls (ASP.NET 3.5) implemented and noticed that each user is given a `UserProfileID`

I'm implementing a public page for each user, [as asked and answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446969/how-do-i-create-a-public-user-profile-page-in-asp-net-3-5), that will use the UserProfileID in the URL.

My question is, can the UserProfileID be used maliciously? Is it OK that anyone can see that persons UserProfileID ?

Is it OK to have something like that in the URL?

(Also, the userIDs are very long, i.e. - `a051fc1b-4f51-485b-a07d-0f378528974e` 
Is there a way to shorten what each user's unique URL is? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your first question is no, there aren't really any security issues posed by exposing a user's id in the URL (as long as you have other means of authorization - don't use that id in the URL to authorize the user).

To answer your second question, the id is a GUID which is quite long.  If you wanted something shorter you would have to store your UserProfile object with a different type as the key in the data store (like an integer which would be shorter).