# loginstatus control not directing to login page if on a custom url

Tags: asp.net, redirect, asp.net-membership, loginstatus

I have public user profile links like `example.com/user/username`.

I have a `loginstatus` control in master page.

if i am on a user page, lets say; `example.com/user/testuser`
and i click on Login, it won't redirect me to `Login.aspx`. Instead gives a `404` error.

How can this be solved?

Thanks for help.

Comment: by showing some code!

Comment: Where is it redirecting you? Or maybe you made authentication required on the login.aspx and it is redirecting in a loop?

Comment: What does your web.config look like? Do you have a relative or hard link t login.aspx? (`~/login.aspx` or `login.aspx`)?

Comment: You've got to use the ResolveUrl() method whenever possible, especially when using Master Pages.

Comment: @FrazellThomas no i don't have anything special in web config. everything is default.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev the loginstatus control works fine for any url except these custom urls. so it shouldnt be anything to do with the actual login page

Comment: @Thousand the thing is there is no special code. i have just gone through microsofts tutorial on this and added loginstatus control for link to login.aspx when user is not logged in. i have also done this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446969/how-do-i-create-a-public-user-profile-page-in-asp-net-3-5 so i have public profile links

Comment: @HanletEscaño can you give an example how to use it

Comment: @btevfik ...so where is it redirecting you?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev i just solved the problem right now. thanks for the help. read my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had problems with relative paths as well. after going through some articles on web. (one of them is this http://www.ifinity.com.au/Blog/EntryId/46/Why-does-Url-Rewriting-break-all-my-image-links)
i resolved the problem by setting `rebaseClientPath` to `false` in `Context.RewritePath` in Global.asax.

Comment: This should be the selected answer IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you write your *URLs* in your `MasterPage` or `WebUSerControl`, use the `ResolveUrl()` method, as such:

```
<a href='<%=ResolveUrl("~/MyLoginPage.aspx")%>'>Login</a>
```

This will ensure that you will get to the right page regardless of the current locationnn.

Comment: i see but there is no where to set up the link to login page if you are using the loginstatus control. by default it is supposed to take you to Login.aspx however since the url is rebased with url rewrite on global.asax, it tries to take you to a page like /something/Login.aspx instead of /Login.aspx